# Common Lisp No Dispatch Character Defined

Tags: syntax, common-lisp, reader-macro

I am currently reading the chapter on read-time macros from Paul Graham's "On Lisp" book.

The problem I am encountering is the following. When I run one of his examples:

```
(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\?
  #’(lambda (stream char1 char2)
    ‘#’(lambda (&rest ,(gensym))
       ,(read stream t nil t))))
```

I get the following error:

```
No dispatch function defined for #\’
```

Why is it happening? Could it be because I am running it at the REPL? What can one do to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PDF from which you are copying the code uses punctuation marks outside the range of basic ASCII characters you are supposed to use here:

```
CL-USER> (char-name #\’)
"RIGHT_SINGLE_QUOTATION_MARK"
```

The usual *quote* symbol should instead use the apostrophe character:

```
CL-USER> (char-name #\')
"APOSTROPHE"
```

The same goes for *backquote*:

```
CL-USER> (char-name #\‘)
"LEFT_SINGLE_QUOTATION_MARK"
```

You should be writing instead:

```
(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\?
                              #'(lambda (stream char1 char2)
                                `#'(lambda (&rest ,(gensym))
                                     ,(read stream t nil t))))
```

The `#'` is not necessary before `lambda`, since Common Lisp also defines a *macro* named `lambda` which expands into `(function (lambda ...))`.

You can test your new read macro as follows:

```
CL-USER> #?10
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (&REST #:G617)) {1001C541FB}>

CL-USER> (funcall *)
10
```

When using SBCL, I obtain warnings about unused variables. This happens because the code declares variables in anonymous functions but never uses them. This is not a serious problem, but generally speaking, it is better to declare which variables are ignored:

```
(set-dispatch-macro-character
 #\# #\?
 (lambda (stream &rest chars)
   (declare (ignore chars))
   (let ((rest (gensym)))
     `(lambda (&rest ,rest)
        (declare (ignore ,rest))
        ,(read stream t nil t)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Could you tell me what your last comment relates to? `(With SBCL, I have a lot of warnings about unused variables, too)`